# Firebase data structure and security rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

Im having trouble with the security rules for firebase and Im not 100% where I am going wrong. I am thinking that maybe I have my data structure wrong:

```
{
"users": {
    "uid": {
        "displayName": "Name";
    }

},
"modules": {
    "id": {
        "title": "buttons",
        "uid": "(user id string)"
    },
    "id": {
        "title": "navbars",
        "uid": "(user id string)"
    }
},
"snippets": {
    "id = moduleID": {
        "id (of snippet)": "(id string)" {
            "uid (user ID)": "(string)",
            "body": {
                "css": "(some code)",
                "html": "(Some code)",
                "name": "(string)",
                "description": "(string)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything in the app works fine, but when I started to add security rules I got access denied errors. Im just wondering if I have the data structure correct in the first place or is the security rules completely wrong?

Security rules:

```
{
"rules": {
    "users": {
        "$uid": {
            // grants write and read access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"

        }
    },
    "snippets": {
        "$uid": {
            // grants write and read access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    },
    "modules": {
        "$uid": {
            // grants write and read access to the owner of this user account whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you see access denied errors? Could you post a snippet of the code that denies the read/write?

Comment: the app works with the normal basic rules, but when updated with the new rules it completely breaks. The console gives this error 
Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at Error (native)

Comment: Try the Simulator tab in your app dashboard; this allows you to analyze how the rules are being applied to any read/write operation, with our without authentication.

Comment: `auth != null && ` is valuable, but technically superfluous here. The `auth.uid === $uid` check will short circuit and still evaluate to false. In this case, just a nuance, but an important concept to understand as it can bite you when you try to use `auth.uid` in complex rules with `||`, where it may short circuit and avoid evaluating the || criteria.

Comment: @kato Thanks for the input, Ill take note. I was completely lost with this and have just started again reading the docs and reading up on NoSql also. I think I need to understand these concepts better instead of trying to force it to work. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems the rules are malformed based on the data structure.

The rules have $uid's in each node but your data doesn't match that. Users has uid but modules has id and snippets has id = moduleID.

$uid is a variable that holds the node name so it can be referenced inside { } so you should (for readability) rename that variable in the other two nodes to something that makes more sense inside each {}. Like in modules, have it $module_id.

However. I think the jest of this is you want to limit reading  snippets and modules to authenticated users. To do that, you can reference the users node.

a .read rule would be something like this

```
"modules": {
    "$module_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && root.child('users/' + auth.id).exists()
    }
```

So your modules node can be read by a user that is auth'd and their uid also appears in the users/ node

Comment: Thanks for your input, I have taken note of this, it makes sense, but still have errors. What I want to happen is for users to see only their data and not the rest of the users data.
Still trying to figure out exactly what going on here with the rules in general so going to do more research, it hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Yeah... It's really challenging getting the rules right for each situation. We have a similar setup where a user (set of users in our case) should only be able to read data from that set of users. I am no expert by any means but after beating my head on it (and the desk) for a couple of weeks we finally got it situated so don't give up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Firebase Bolt compiler for rules?  I had to write some complex rules and doing it by hand gets confusing very quickly.

Below is what it would looks like.  Very easy to make changes, compile and try them out.

```
//current logged in user
isUser(uid) = auth != null && auth.uid == uid;
//does this module id exist
hasValidModule(module_id) = root['modules'][module_id] != null;

//dont let anyone read or write to top node
path / {
    read() = false;
    write() = false;
}
path /users/$user_id 
{   
    write() = isUser($user_id);
    read() = isUser($user_id);
}
path /snippets/$module_id/$snipit_id/$user_id 
{   
    write() = isUser($user_id) && hasValidModule($module_id);
    read() = isUser($user_id);
}
path /modules/$user_id 
{   
    write() = isUser($user_id);
    read() = isUser($user_id);
}
```

Here's the json it spits out:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
      }
    },
    "snippets": {
      "$module_id": {
        "$snipit_id": {
          "$user_id": {
            ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
            ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id && newData.parent().parent().parent().parent().child('modules').child($module_id).val() != null"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "modules": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $user_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There's some info on the Firebase blog but the doc that really helped me is this

https://github.com/firebase/bolt/blob/master/docs/language.md

Comment: Thanks for the input, that looks great. But I wanted to try and understand the rules and how they work first before using any tools. The rules it gave out did not work either. I have realised that I need to re-structure my data and Angular code to get the results I was looking for. I was trying to use the rules as a filter, which I now realise is not what it is meant to do. I will update this post when I get it figured out. Thanks again.